# wrong number of arguments (5 for 1..4) Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two table in `SQLLite` *Team* and *Users*

When I am creating a user, I want use `SELECT` to select the team.

Unfortunately, I have a problem:

> wrong number of arguments (5 for 1 to 4)

Form:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :team ,"team"%><br>
    <%= f.select(:team , :team_id,Team.all,:id,:name)%>
  </div>
```

*User* and *Team* was creating using a `scaffold`.

Comment: Try changing it to `<%= f.select(:team_id,Team.all,:id,:name)%>`.If it didn't work,then post your full `form code`.

Comment: try `f.select("team", "team_id", Team.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] })`

Comment: Unfortunately does not work;/

undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

It is a form of adding user

http://www.wklejto.pl/207877

User controller

http://www.wklejto.pl/207878

team controller

http://www.wklejto.pl/207879


Of course, the user model is

   belongs_to: team

and the model team is

   has_many: users

Comment: Index user view http://wklejto.pl/207880

Answer (score 3):

If you want the pattern where you pass a collection and the names of methods for extracting the form value and the display value then you need to use `collection_select` instead.

Furthermore, when used with a form builder (ie when doing `f.collection_select` you drop the first argument, since the object that is being edited is implicit. For example you would do

```
  <%= f.collection_select :team_id, Team.all, :id, :name %>
```

Comment: Ok it works!

I have one problem when I add user I choose the team, I do not see the index of each team in the list of users.

Answer (score 1):

Look in doc [`select(object, method, choices, options = {}, html_options = {})`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select):
example:

```
select("post", "person_id", Person.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] })
```

You should use block in arguments for build array with `id` and `name` like:

```
<%= f.select(:team , :team_id, Team.all.collect {|t| [ t.id, t.name ] })%>
```

Difference in your code:

```
<%= f.select(:team , :team_id, Team.all, :id, :name )%>
```

`:team` first arg, `:team_id` second arg, `Team.all` third arg, `:id` four arg, `:name` five. Too excess.

Right way:

```
<%= f.select(:team , :team_id, Team.all.collect {|t| [ t.id, t.name ] })%>
```

`:team` first arg, `:team_id` second arg, `Team.all.collect {|t| [ t.id, t.name ] }` third arg.